# React native passing variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, binding, frontend

I have a function and I want to pass a variable inside that function.
This **sendDraft** function will receive parameter

```
sendDraft(billnumber) {
    axios
      .post("http://192.168.0.111:3000/sendDraft", {
        invoice: billnumber,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

That is the function which will send the parameter to **sendDraft** function

```
let drafts = this.state.invoice.map((invc) => {
      return (
        <Card key={invc.invoiceId}>
          <Card.Title>Invoice Number: {invc.billnumber}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Divider />
          <View>
            <Text>
              Customer's address:
              {invc.address}
            </Text>
            <Text>Customer's email: {invc.email}</Text>
            <Text>Total Price: {invc.price}</Text>
          </View>
          <Button //Button which will be pressed to send parameter
            title="SEND DRAFT"
            onPress={this.sendDraft.bind(this, invc.billnumber)}
          />
        </Card>
      );
    });
```

That is the button (the last Button)

I am sure that invc.billnumber is not null.

but when I click the button the variable is not passed and the update statement wont find the record.

(API works perfectly in postman).

What is the problem and how do we pass variables in react native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm that the invc.billnumber is not null or undefined you have to debug them.
Console it before return to check whether invc.billnumber is not null or undefined.

```
console.log(invc.billnumber);
```

Second issue might be with the binding where you are implementing onPress event.
You can do the binding in the constructor by using ES6 syntax:

```
export default class Abc extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.sendDraft= this.sendDraft.bind(this);
  }
```

And then:

```
let drafts = this.state.invoice.map((invc) => {
      console.log(invc.billnumber); //To check invc.billnumber value
      return (
        <Card key={invc.invoiceId}>
          <Card.Title>Invoice Number: {invc.billnumber}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Divider />
          <View>
            <Text>
              Customer's address:
              {invc.address}
            </Text>
            <Text>Customer's email: {invc.email}</Text>
            <Text>Total Price: {invc.price}</Text>
          </View>
          <Button
            title="SEND DRAFT"
             onPress={() => this.sendDraft(invc.billnumber)}> //Bind like this
          />
        </Card>
      );
    });
```

Comment: `sendDraft(billnumber) {
    console.log(billnumber);
    axios
      .post("http://192.168.0.111:3000/sendDraft", {
        invoice: billnumber,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }`
i did that and the console.log() returned a value so even in the function the billnumber is not null

Comment: and i did what you stated in your answer it might of been why the billnumber is now showing thank you!

Comment: Ok. Go ahead with the binding issue. It seems like you are not binding and sending parameter correctly. Read the second issue in my answer.

Comment: can i ask you another question in private?

Comment: @jayzee Ok,I am available for help!

Comment: can you send me a private message i don't know how to do it sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221745/discussion-between-suleman-ahmad-and-jayzee).